# Steelseries Sibera Crossplatform Mac

Tags: mac, microphone, headset

So I need to get a new headset and I've been looking for one that will work on all the devices I plan to use it on (PC, Mac, XBOX) and came across this:

http://steelseries.com/products/consoles/steelseries-siberia-v2-cross-platform-headset

It says it's Mac compatible, but I can't actually find anything on it. No reviews say anything about it working on Mac. For reference, I've got one of the newer Macbook Pros that have the pair of audio ports, audio line in and audio line out. My old microphone doesn't work on it because I can't connect the 3.5mm mic into the line in.

Does anyone know if this will work? I don't mind if it has a USB connection for Mac, just so long as I can get it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has a USB connection from the converter that will work, so I guess it's fine. Would have preferred to have something that didn't take one of my few USB ports, but considering Mac uses a stupid audio line-in port, I can't complain.